# Iphone application using webview

Tags: iphone, app-store

I've created a web application using asp.net. I customized it form mobile(jQuery Mobile) .
I created an iphone application that has a web view that shows the website.

Is this will be applied by Apple to publish this application???

Regards,
Moayyad

Answer (score 1):

If the **only purpose** of the app is showing the webview with the website, and it does **absolutely nothing else,** then it will *most likely* be rejected. However, if showing the website is just a small part of its functionality, and it does some other useful things as well, then using a webview for displaying your own website is OK, as far as I know.

Note, however, that I/we can only make assumptions and guesses. **Nobody except Apple knows what exactly will happen to your app** - there are numerous cases when an app was rejected for a feature which another *approved* app had, so there are inconsistencies in the AppStore approval policy of Apple. **Don't expect anything.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. They prefer use of HTML5 in webapp. Try to review the Apple guidelines for building web app.